# How to check if my code is getting recompiled in GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

How can I check if my code is getting recompiled by GCC or not. For example if I type:

```
g++ -c test.cpp
```

is there a way that GCC tells you that the code is being recompiled in to a new object file because test.cpp has changed. I know I can check the object file's timestamp in terminal but is there an option in GCC which tells you that? Thanks.

Comment: This question relates to your build system (make, waf, cmake, etc.) rather than GCC itself. However, you can look at the timestamp of the file `ls -l test.o` if you're not sure.

Comment: To further clarify @robert's comment: when you type `g++ -c test.cpp`, it will *always* recompile that file. It's the buildsystem driver (such as `make`) which decides whether a file is outdated or not and whether *the compiler needs to be invoked for the file.* The up-to-date question is not "does the compiler recompile the file?", but "is the compiler told to recompile the file?"

Comment: I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc will always build if you tell it to build. Like robert said in the comments it is up to your build system to figure out if the file needs updating.
In make you could just print an info if your target is being hit or you could do a checksum (md5sum or so) of your binary the beginning and end of your build.